# Continuous Function on closed interval

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

I am having trouble understanding what this question is asking , by "$f$ has a zero" does it mean "there exists $x$ $\in$ $[a,b]$ such that $f(x)$=$0$? any help on how to answer this question in both techniques described would be very much appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it means that either there is an $x \in \left[a,b\right]$ such that $f\left(x\right)=0$ or you have the other condition.

Hint: use that you have both maximum and minimum for a continuous function on a closed interval. Then you have two cases: either maximum and minimum have the same sign (and then you will find your $\varepsilon$), or they have different signs and there you can use the intermediate value theorem. Of course there is also a third case, when maximum or minimum is zero; in that case it is obvious we have a zero.

Comment: ok, so **first case $max(x)=0$ or $min(x)=0$ , so obviously contains a zero.**Second case $max(x)>0$  $min(x)<0$  then by IVT there exists $x$ $\in$ $[a,b]$ such that $f(x)=0$ and ** Third Case if $max(x)>0$ and $min(x)>0$ then $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ $\in$ $[a,b]$ and so there exists $\epsilon >0$  such that for all $x$ $\in$ $[a,b]$ $|f(x)|$ $>$ $\epsilon$ would this answer suffice?

Comment: I would also have to add the case where $max(x)<0$ and $min(x)<0$ but similarly to case 3 answer still holds as it is $|f(x)|$ we are looking at.

Comment: Yes. If max and min are $>0$, then your $\varepsilon$ is any value $0<\varepsilon<min$. If both are negative, you take absolute value and consider $0<\varepsilon<|max|$, since is max the closest to zero

Answer (score 1):

Yes it means exactly that.

Note that the graph of $f$ on $[a,b]$ is a closed bounded set, because of the continuity. So is the graph of the zero function $g=0$ on $[a,b]$.

But if $2$ compacts have their distance $0$, they necessarily intersect. (this happens if there's no such $\varepsilon>0$)